# How to redirect to another component after google signin in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router-dom

I want to redirect to `<Chats />` component after the user has signed in through their gmail ID. I also want the `uid` and `userName` to be send as props to the component, but I'm not able to redirect to that. I've tried `<Navigate />` inside the promise, I've tried `window.location.replace('')` too. `<Navigate />` seems to do nothing and `window.location.replace('')` redirects but the props are empty, I have no idea what is happening, can anyone help?

> Here is the code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { signInWithPopup, signOut } from 'firebase/auth'
import { auth, db, provider } from './firebase-config'
import { set, ref, onValue } from 'firebase/database'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import Chats from './components/Chats'
import Homepage from './components/Homepage'

const App = () => {

    const [uid, setUid] = useState('')
    const [userName, setUserName ] = useState('')
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false)

    const signInWithGoogle = () => {
        signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
            .then(result => {
                setUid(result.user.uid)
                setUserName(result.user.displayName)
                setRedirect(true)
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    const signOutWithGoogle = () => {
      signOut(auth, provider)
      setUserName('')
      setRedirect(false)
    }

    redirect && (<Navigate to='/chats' />)

  return (
    <Router>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Homepage signInWithGoogle={signInWithGoogle} signOutWithGoogle={signOutWithGoogle} />} />
            <Route path="/chats" element={<Chats uid={uid} name={userName}/>} />
        </Routes>

    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at `useNavigate` https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate

Comment: You can pass `uid` and `userName` using the state object as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put both homepage and chats under the same url path and render the page that meets the requirements

```
 <Routes>
     <Route path="/" element={uid || userName ? <Chats uid={uid} name={userName}/> :<Homepage signInWithGoogle={signInWithGoogle} signOutWithGoogle={signOutWithGoogle} />} />
 </Routes>
```

or

```
<Routes>
    {uid || userName ?
       <Route path="/chats" element={<Chats uid={uid} name={userName}/>} />
       :
       <Route path="/" element={<Homepage signInWithGoogle={signInWithGoogle} signOutWithGoogle={signOutWithGoogle} />} />
     }
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Issues

You can't return JSX from a callback and expect it to be rendered into the DOM and do anything.

Don't use the `window.location` method as this will reload the page, thus remounting your app, so any React state will be lost if it wasn't persisted to localStorage or similar.

## Solution 1

Use the `useNavigate` hook to access the `navigate` function and issue an imperative redirect with the appropriate data sent along in route state. In order for the `App` component to use the `useNavigate` hook though, you will need to lift the `Router` above it in the ReactTree.

Example:

```
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then(result => {
        const { displayName, uid } = result.user.uid;
        navigate(
          "/chats",
          {
            replace: true,
            state: { uid, userName: displayName },
          }
        );
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  const signOutWithGoogle = () => {
    signOut(auth, provider);
    setUserName('');
    setRedirect(false);
  };

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Homepage signInWithGoogle={signInWithGoogle} signOutWithGoogle={signOutWithGoogle} />} />
      <Route path="/chats" element={<Chats />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

index.js or wherever `App` is rendered

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Router>
  <App />
</Router>
```

Chat

Use the `useLocation` hook to access the passed route state values.

```
const { state } = useLocation();

...

const { uid, userName } = state || {};
```

## Solution 2

If you don't want to send the data in route state you could try using the local `uid` and `userName` state and still use the `navigate` function to imperatively redirect. You'll still need to lift the `Router` up the ReactTree.

Example:

```
const App = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [uid, setUid] = useState('');
  const [userName, setUserName ] = useState('');

  const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then(result => {
        setUid(result.user.uid);
        setUserName(result.user.displayName);
        navigate("/chats", { replace: true });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  const signOutWithGoogle = () => {
    signOut(auth, provider);
    setUserName('');
    setRedirect(false);
  };

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Homepage signInWithGoogle={signInWithGoogle} signOutWithGoogle={signOutWithGoogle} />} />
      <Route path="/chats" element={<Chats uid={uid} name={userName}/>} />
    </Routes>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In Firebase, there's one function that can help you to implement some code when the authentication change (i.e.: after logging in using an email, after signing up, after logging out, ...), which is:

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth: Auth, nextOrObserver: NextOrObserver<User>, error?: ErrorFn, completed?: CompleteFn): Unsubscribe;
```

Where:

- `auth`: The Auth Instance
- `nextOrObserver`: a callback triggered on authentication change
- `error`: a callback triggered on error
- `completed` (optional): a callback triggered when observer is removed

You can read more at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#onauthstatechanged

Basically, when using this function, you are subscribing to the authentication observer, and this function returns an unsubscribe function. Hence, this is can be perfectly used with `useEffect` in React. After seeing your problem, you can put these lines into the `App` component:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    // When no user is logged in and the path is '/chats' => redirect to login page
    if(user === null && window.location.href.includes('/chats')) {
      if(window.location.href.includes('/chats')) return; // This is important, if this line is not presented, the page will reload infinitely
      window.location.href = '/'; // Redirect to '/'
    }

    // After user is logged in => redirect to '/chats'
    if(user !== null && window.location.href.includes('/')) {
      if(window.location.href.includes('/')) return;
      window.location.href = '/chats'; // Redirect to '/chats'
    }
  });
  return unsubcribe; // This must also included
})
```

When seeing your code, I see that you put all authentication methods and states in `App` component. I recommend you to create a React context that contains those lines of code (and also the above code), since they should be global.